# React app crashing when user access page where the actions were not dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-router

I'm starting to create my first app using REACT - HOOK - REDUX AND REACT ROUTER.
Currently, the app is working well only if the user goes to the home page, which does not use any react state (it is a static page with a welcome). If the user uses the others links, the app is crashing because there is no data inside the redux state.
How can I manage this case? I would like to display a button to execute the refresh.

Let me show you the current code:

**App.js**

```
import './styles.css';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import { Header } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import BurgerSidebar from './components/sidebar/BurgerSidebar';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { requestData } from "./components/redux/actions"; 
import LoadingOverlay from 'react-loading-overlay';



function App() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const DataReducer = useSelector((state) => state.data);


  const dataLoadingStatus = DataReducer.isLoading;


  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    

    dispatch(requestData());


   }, [refresh]);


  return (

<div id="App"> 

<LoadingOverlay
  active={dataLoadingStatus}
  spinner
  text='Loading your content...'
  >


  <div className="ui  inverted segment">
    <Header as='h1' textAlign='center'>
      <Header.Content>
       Data Dashboard
      </Header.Content>
    </Header>

  </div>
  
  <BurgerSidebar  />

</LoadingOverlay>
</div>

  );

}

export default App;
```

Then this is an example of component where the router can redirect from the homepage and an user can access directly.
Example of **Dashboard.js**

```
import {React} from 'react'
import { Header, Container, Segment, Icon, Divider, Card, Grid, Statistic } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import {  useSelector } from "react-redux";


const Dashboard = () => {







   const DataReducer = useSelector((state) => state.data);

   const customData = DataReducer.data;
   const totalusers = customData.users.length;

return(


  <main id="page-wrap">
    <Container text>
    <Header as='h2'>Dashboard</Header>
    <Segment>

    <Divider horizontal>
       <Header as='h4'>
          <Icon name='chart bar' />
              Statistics
        </Header>
    </Divider>

      <Grid columns={1} relaxed='very'>
        <Grid.Column>
        <Card fluid>
          <Card.Content>
          <Card.Header>Total Users</Card.Header>

          <Statistic>
          <Statistic.Value>{totalusers}</Statistic.Value>
          <Statistic.Label>Users of the system</Statistic.Label>
          </Statistic>
          


          </Card.Content>
          </Card>     
        </Grid.Column>
        
        
    </Grid>

</Segment>
    </Container>

  </main>


);


}

export default Dashboard
```

So, the idea would be to put a check if the state.data is empty but unfortunately seems do not work.
Any suggestion?

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to solving this.
You can either initialize your state when you create your store.
https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/initializing-state

Or your components should be written in a way that can handle undefined or null state variables

Comment: thanks! I did an error in the check of the status thinking that it was 'undefined', but it was an array empty. Now putting the condition if [[ data.length === 0 ]] everything is working well.